# Why are the results of two search statements inconsistent?

Tags: openfda

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(receivedate:[20040108+TO+20210401])+AND+patient.drug.medicinalproduct:%22IBUPROFEN%22&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact
```

Using the above search request, I get values as ([full response](https://0bin.net/paste/OAG1lSoL#+Fi57xXJT869JGfXYWDmwDl0EHHYa5euxJCRSyUHce2))

> "term": "PAIN", "count": 9080

.

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=(receivedate:[20040108+TO+20210401])+AND+patient.drug.medicinalproduct.exact:%22IBUPROFEN%22+AND+patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact:%22PAIN%22
```

Using the above search request, I get ([full response](https://0bin.net/paste/rx1E5xwh#MCuQ0jJOPiXoMfO3M-GQlVnNZpRcpzQXOwot2LJkTkk))

> "total": 2914

How does the above two search requests differentiate so that the result are different?

Answer (score 0):

Your former query is using `patient.drug.medicinalproduct` while the latter is using `patient.drug.medicinalproduct.exact`. The `exact` part is what makes the difference.

Comment: I disagree, what about the part `PAIN`?

Comment: diff checker (original is the first query): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHmVA.png [good piece of software](http://incaseofstairs.com/jsdiff/)